# 'No such file or directory' when I am trying to format Logical Volume

Tags: centos, partition, lvm

I am trying to create Logical Volume on CentOS 7 on EC2 instance. After attaching the volume I am creating partition using `fdisk`, then I am starting the Logical Volume creation:

```
pvcreate /dev/xvda1
vgcreate vgname /dev/xvda1
lvcreate -L 68G vgname -n lvname
```

After this implementation I am trying to format the Logical Volume as ext4 but when I run `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vgname-lvname` I am receiving the following error:

```
mkfs.ext4: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Does `which mke2fs` return anything? If so, you're probably missing a symlink to `mkfs.ext4`.

Comment: @muru The more weird thing is that `mke2fs` is even not available on the system.

Comment: Apparently you're missing the `e2fsprogs` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to [install](http://www.kodkast.com/linux-package-installation-steps?pkg=e4fsprogs) `e4fsprogs` CentOS package before you want to create an ext4 filesystem.

In general, `mkfs` is just a *front-end* for a series of `mkfs.*` binaries.

See the following example:

```
root@locutus:/home/asd# strace -f -e trace=execve mkfs -t asdasd /dev/whatever
execve("/sbin/mkfs", ["mkfs", "-t", "asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
execve("/sbin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/sbin/fs.d/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/sbin/fs/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/sbin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/sbin/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin\n/mkfs.asdasd", ["mkfs.asdasd", "/dev/whatever"], [/* 18 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mkfs.asdasd: No such file or directory
root@locutus:/home/asd#
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your RHEL version doesnt support ext4 but you can remedy this by installing e4fsprogs with yum install or by downloading the package and then  use ftp to move it to your server then install with rpm -ivh